# IndexError list out of range for mastermind game in Python

Tags: python

The following code seems to be working fine until I get to compare_choice. I don't know why it's giving me an IndexError. I've tried numerous things including setting up a whole new index function and scoured the web - and the dozens of explanations on this site of course in search of an answer. I understand what this error is all about, but I don't know why I'm getting the error in my case. The user can only choose four colors from an array.

As my frustrations grew, I wrote comments for each line in an attempt to organize my thoughts and hopefully catch the error. I have no doubt it is something I'm going to feel stupid over.

This is my first dynamic language and obviously I'm still new at it, but I've been working really hard to understand it...

### Class

```
#class Master:
   ##Print beginning of game.
    print("Let's play a Mastermind-ish Game!")
    print("Guess my pattern of colors in the correct sequence in 15 tries!")
    print("Your color choices are:")
    print("[R]ed [B]lue [Y]ellow")
    print("[W]hite [O]range and [G]reen")
    ##End print beginning of game.

    def check_input(user_input): ##creates function passing user_input.
        user_input = input("Enter your guess as 4 letters. (XXXX):") ##Creates variable to get user_input.
        while True: ##Creates while loop to keep the following going until the user_input is valid.
            if len(user_input) != 4: ##If user enters more than 5 characters, print the following.
                user_input = input("Please enter ONLY 4 letters. (XXXX):")
            else: ##If user enters something else
                letters = list(user_input.upper()) ##Creates variable definging what constitues as a letter from user_input.
                incorrect_letters = False ##creates variable to identify whether or not user_input is valid for choice list.
                for letter in letters: ##creates index type of variable for checking letter choice.
                    if letter not in ['R','G','Y','B','O','W']: ##If user_input letter does not match list...
                        incorrect_letters = True  ##Then the index variable is True
                if incorrect_letters == True: ##If incorrect letters is True, then print the following.
                    user_input = input("Your choices again are R G Y B O W. Please enter 4 LETTERS only. (XXXX):")
                else: ##If none of the above occurs, the user has entered valid data.
                    return user_input ##Return value for main program.
```

### END CLASS

### Main

```
import random ##Import random module for computer's code.
import mclass ##Import class module for user's guess.

remaining_guesses = 15 ##15 chances to guess the right sequence
choice = [] ##Initializes comp choice variable as list.
guess = []  ##Initializes user guess variable as list.
correct_position = 0 ##Creates empty value for position that increments when user guesses correct position.
correct_color = 0 ##Creates empty value for color that increments when user guesses correct color.

def comp_choice(): ##Creates function for computer's choice.
    sequence = [] ##Initializes sequence variable as list.
    for i in range(4): ##Creates structure for computer's random choice.
        choice.append(random.choice(['R','G','Y','B','O','W'])) ##Implements the random module.
        return sequence ##Returns computer's random choice.
comp_choice() ##Function call to comp_choice.

user = mclass.Master() ##calls class and defines it as variable: user.
print(user.check_input()) ##Prints variable with function call.

remaining_guesses -= 1  ##Deducts guess upon action.

while remaining_guesses > 0: ##Initiates loop for as long as program is True.
    guess = []  ##Initializes user guess variable as list.
    correct_position = 0 ##Creates empty value for position that increments when user guesses correct position.
    correct_color = 0 ##Creates empty value for color that increments when user guesses correct color.

    def compare_choice(user): ##Function to figure out what the user has correct.
        for i in range(4):  ##For loop to handle what the user has correct.
            if guess[i] == choice[i]: ##If user guess matches the computer choice...
                correct_position += 1 ##then add correct_position.
                return correct_position ##and return for later use.

            if guess[i] == choice[i]:##If user guess matches the computer choice...
                correct_color += 1 ##then add correct_position.
                return correct_color ##and return for later use.

            if correct_position > 0: ##If user selects at least one correct position print the following.
                print("You have",correct_position,"color(s) in the correct position.")

            if correct_color > 0:  ##If user selects at least one correct color print the following.
                print("You have",correct_color,"correct color(s) in the wrong position.")

            if correct_position == 0 and correct_color == 0: ##If user has everything wrong print the following.
                print("You have NO correct colors in ANY position.")

            if correct_position == 4: ##If user gets everything right, print the following.
                print("WAHOO! You won in",12-remaining_guesses,"guesses. Nice work!")

            if remaining_guesses == 0: ##If user runs out of guesses print the following.
                print("Sorry! Out of tries!")

    compare_choice(user) ##Function call for compare_choice.
```

### Update: Error

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Let's play a Mastermind-ish Game!
Guess my pattern of colors in the correct sequence in 15 tries!
Your color choices are:
[R]ed [B]lue [Y]ellow
[W]hite [O]range and [G]reen
Enter your guess as 4 letters. (XXXX):1234
Your choices again are R G Y B O W. Please enter 4 LETTERS only. (XXXX):12345
Please enter ONLY 4 letters. (XXXX):jklm
Your choices again are R G Y B O W. Please enter 4 LETTERS only. (XXXX):rgyb
rgyb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Whited/Desktop/Classes/Programming/Final Project/masterish.py", line 52, in <module>
    compare_choice(user) ##Function call for compare_choice.
  File "C:/Users/Whited/Desktop/Classes/Programming/Final Project/masterish.py", line 29, in compare_choice
    if guess[i] == choice[i]: ##If user guess matches the computer choice...
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Please provide the **full traceback** for the `IndexError` within the question itself.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -Sorry about that, I meant to make sure I put that in since other posts requested it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `guess` variable is initialized as an empty list at

```
guess = []
```

It never has any elements, so the

```
if guess[i] == choice[i]: ##If user guess matches the computer choice...
```

would fail even for value `i` of `0`. You probably wanted the `guess` variable to contain the `guess` entered by the user instead...

Comment: hmmm ok, I'll work on figuring that one out. I changed a few things already and got two different errors, but I'll do some more work and post an update. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, a programmer usually works the program in pieces, testing it, it looks like you wrote all of the functionality in one go and then try to fix the bugs...

Comment: I do that, but in this case I made the mistake of creating the class after the program was written, now I'm trying to backtrack a bit, changed a few things to make it work and got stuck.